# Resetting ScrollView position to the top of the page

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I'm trying to make the scroll reset to the top of the page when a view appears (e.g. when you navigate back from a navigation link). The ScrollView is embedded within a NavigationView with a large title.

Using the code below, I'm able to reset the scroll to the first element on the page using `ScrollViewReader` and `scrollTo`.

However, I'd like for the view to scroll all the way to the top such that the large navigation bar title reappears. Instead, I just see the inline title.

Is there a better way to reset the scroll to go to the very top of the page and show the large navigation bar title?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { value in
                    ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination"), label: { Text("\(i)") })
                                .padding(.bottom, 100)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .id(i)
                    }
                    .onAppear() {
                        value.scrollTo(0)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Scroll Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the api does not allow for such functionality. Lets hope next week changes that.

Meanwhile you could implement this workaround: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127737

It works by forcing the view to redraw by clearing out the data.

For your example to work you have to

1. Create a `@State` variable like

`@State var data = Array(0..<10)`

2. Replace your `ForEach` with

`ForEach(data, id: \.self)`

2. Change your code within the `onAppear`

to

```
.onAppear {
    data = []
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
        data = Array(1..<10)
    }
```